# Sending SIGINT to docker container from inside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have have been trying to make it so that I am able to shutdown a docker container from inside. I have read that using `tini` is the best way to do this.

I have added `init: true` to my docker-compose.yml and I can see that docker-init is running as `PID 1`. However the only command that lets me shutdown the container from my shell script is using `kill 1`, but I want to gracefully shutdown my container so that it can do some cleanup.

I have tried using commands like `kill -SIGINT 1` which results in the error `kill: Illegal option -S`
or `kill -INT 1` and `kill -2 1` which both seem to do nothing at all.

I can't seem to figure out the command that I can use. If there is an alternative to `init` that would also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

The application inside the container doesn't need any special setup in order to shut down; it can just run its own shutdown sequence and exit, and when it does exit, the container will exit as well.  If you're trying to do this from a debugging shell you launched with `docker exec`, you can just use `docker stop` to send SIGTERM and then SIGKILL.  (...and reserve the `docker exec` shell for *debugging*; it should not be the primary way you interact with your container.)

If you need to send a container a non-default signal, [`docker kill`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/) has that option:

```
docker kill --signal SIGINT container_name
```

In terms of using **kill**(1) in a debugging shell, the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) for the underlying **kill**(2) function notes:

> The only signals that can be sent to process ID 1, the *init* process, are those for which *init* has explicitly installed signal handlers. This is done to assure the system is not brought down accidentally.

It looks like `tini` [collects and forwards](https://github.com/krallin/tini/blob/master/src/tini.c#L456) a pretty broad range of signals, everything except SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGABRT, SIGTRAP, SIGSYS, and the uncatchable signals (notably SIGKILL).  Since it does register a signal handler, `kill -INT 1` should forward that signal on to the actual container process.  (Its pid is *probably* 2, so `kill -INT 2` should also tell the process to stop.)

Comment: I am trying to do this in a healthcheck script where I want to shutdown the container gracefully. `kill 1` works but i want to use SIGINT and `kill -INT 1` does nothing.

Comment: When I use `top` inside the container, I can see that `docker-init` has `PID 1`

Comment: I'd suggest launching the health check from outside the container if you can.  (This is more or less the pattern Kubernetes uses: if a health check fails, the orchestrator kills off the container from the outside.)  If you have to do it from inside the container, you could in principle make the health checker launch and then monitor the server you're trying to run; maybe this replaces the init process.